# password_hash, Password_default causing issue

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

i have 2 register pages with different codes but i want them to return same password hash ! or at least accepted format by Password_verify
first is:

```
function _password_hash($password) {
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}

  $db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_phone, user_password, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_gender, user_birthdate, user_registered, user_activation_key) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", secure($args['username']), secure($args['email']), secure($args['phone']), secure(_password_hash($args['password'])), secure(ucwords($args['first_name'])), secure(ucwords($args['last_name'])), secure($args['gender']), secure($args['birth_date']), secure($date), secure($activation_key) )) or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
```

and second is:

```
$user_firstname = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$user_lastname = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$user_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$user_email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
$user_password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['user_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
$hash = $mysqli->escape_string(md5(time()*rand(1, 9999)));

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_name, user_email, user_password, hash) "
        . "VALUES ('$user_firstname','$user_lastname','$user_name','$user_email','$user_password', '$hash')";
```

password output doesn't the same

Comment: Of course it doesn't give you the same, they'll be generating different salts. Better question is how you seem to have got to a place where you need 2 different registrations, in 2 different ways...

Comment: Side note: Don't escape passwords, you may be doing more harm than good. `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` already take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

The function `password_hash()` never returns the same password hash because of salting, but it always produce a format accepted by `password_verify()`. If this is not the case, check that the hash is stored as `varchar(255)` and that both pages use the same PHP version.

If you use password_hash() neither escape the user password, nor should the password hash be escaped (it is already in a safe form).